# Data at Root Level is Invalid

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I keep getting the following error -->***Data at Root Level is Invalid*** when trying to parse an XML string

```
foreach (var item in adxGroupQueryResult.quickQueryInfos)
{
    string x = item.label.ToString();
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(x);

    var dic = (from country in doc.Root.Elements()
            select new { language = country.Attribute("language").Value, text = country.Attribute("text").Value })
        .Distinct()
        .ToDictionary(country => country.language, country => country.text);
}
```

Value in `x` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<i18nText>
    <Country code="DE" language="de" text="nach Datum" />
    <Country code="US" language="en" text="by Date" />
</i18nText>
```

Update:

[image]

Comment: The string you posted is valid.  Make sure there are no spaces at the beginning.  Not sure why you need .ToString().  With controls you should just use the Text property.

Comment: @jdweng I tried removing `ToString()`,still the same issue.

Comment: Strings in .NET are not UTF-8 encoded. XDocument.Parse will be breaking on `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Could there be some hidden characters at the beginning of the string preventing it from being parsed?

Comment: You can validate the xml in VS menu : Project : Add NEW Item : Xml File.  Then paste xml in view.   The errors will show up in the error list like compiler errors.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning How to fix this issue?

Comment: Do what the [XDocument.Parse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse) documentation does and remove the `encoding=UTF-8"`. All of their examples start with `<?xml version="1.0"?> `.

Comment: What is wrong.  We cannot see the error.  It must be an issue that gets removed when you post the string.

Comment: If it is whitespase try x.Trim() to remove any spaces at beginning and end.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have tried `string x = item.label.Replace("encoding=\"UTF -8\"", "");` .. seems not working

Comment: You have a space character before your `-8`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - `XDocument.Parse()` will **not** throw an error on `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kmj94T.  Actually, the code and XML shown in the question seem to work perfectly.

Comment: This works here, `var doc = XDocument.Parse(x.Replace("encoding=\"UTF-8\"", ""));`

Comment: @techno - could there be some non-printing characters at the beginning of the string `x` such as a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: @dbc Please see the update...

Comment: @jdweng Please see update.

Comment: So you removed all the unicode characters from the string using regex.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(this is not an answer, would be messy in comments)

```
void Main()
{
    string x = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
    <i18nText>
        <Country code=""DE"" language=""de"" text=""nach Datum"" />
        <Country code=""US"" language=""en"" text=""by Date"" />
    </i18nText>";

    var doc = XDocument.Parse(x);

    var dic = (from country in doc.Root.Elements()
               select new { language = country.Attribute("language").Value, text = country.Attribute("text").Value })
        .Distinct()
        .ToDictionary(country => country.language, country => country.text);

    foreach (var kv in dic)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key}:{kv.Value}");
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
de:nach Datum
en:by Date
```

There is no error. Probably x doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Comment: Thanks .. let me try it.. is there any way to add an extra unique element to the dictionary?

Comment: @techno, yes you can use dic.Add("uniqueKey","uniqueValue");